# Re-render items of a FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, use-state

I'm trying to make an expandable FlatList in React-Native. When one presses the "TouchableOpacity" Component, it should now display the description (item.Beschreibung). I try to do this, by adding every item that is rendered by the renderItem function to an array if it has been pressed. It somehow doesn't work, because the condition in the "renderItem" is not checked again. How can I fix this?

```
const clickedItems = []
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)

const addMoreItems = (x) => {
    if (hasBeenClicked(x.Name) == false){
        clickedItems.push(x.Name)
    } else{
        clickedItems.splice(clickedItems.indexOf(x.Name), 1)
    }
  }

const hasBeenClicked = (x) => {
    if (clickedItems.includes(x) == true){
        setIsClicked(true)
    } else {
        setIsClicked(false)
    }
    return isClicked
}

const renderItem =({item, index})=>{
    if (hasBeenClicked(item.Name) == false){
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={addMoreItems(item)}><Text>{item.Name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={addMoreItems(item)}>
                <Text>{item.Name}</Text>
                <Text>{item.Beschreibung}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:18}}>Informationen zur Übung: {kurse[kursIndex].Uebungen[uebungsIndex].Name}</Text>
        <Text></Text>
        <Text style={{textAlign:"justify"}}>{kurse[kursIndex].Uebungen[uebungsIndex].Info}</Text>
        <FlatList  
            data={kurse[kursIndex].Uebungen[uebungsIndex].KognitiveProzesse}
            keyExtractor={item=>item.id}
            renderItem={renderItem}
        ></FlatList>
    </View>
)
```

Comment: Quite a few issues: (1) You invoke `addMoreItems` immediately instead of when pressed, (2) `clickedItems` isn't stored in state or React ref, so it is cleared/reset every render, (3) React state updates are asynchronous so updating state in `hasBeenClicked` doesn't allow you to return the enqueued `isClicked` state value, (4) your render functions shouldn't have side-effect such as updating component state.

Answer (score 0):

React components are only re-rendered if their props or state changes.

The `renderItem` function will only be re-evaluated when `kurse[kursIndex].Uebungen[uebungsIndex].KognitiveProzesse` changes.

I would suggest moving the `isExpanded` state inside the child component. Create a `CognitiveProcessListItem` component (if I understand your code correctly ) and add `[isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = React.useState(false)` inside.